# How to add .5 rating for products magento?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Currently, we are having ratings with 5 stars options. But I would like to have 5 stars with 10 options incrementing by .5.

Actual options

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Expected options

```
0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 ,2.5 ,3 ,3.5 ,4 ,4.5 ,5
```

Example: For 3.5 rating we would like to have option like this

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add by script or ?

Comment: You cannot manage it with script as every star is a radio button hidden. How do you select half radio?

Comment: basically, the idea is to have 10 radio buttons and manage it via css/js to have like it as 5 stars. Is there a way to increase the rating entity from 5->10 with the above options? Magento having rating field as an integer.